# Would a 'function_not_found_handle ()' loadable bash builtin be possible?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, bash-functions

I wrote a function to handle unknown commands in bash
via `command_not_found_handle ()`.
My intention is to source scripts on demand and access
its functions inside the handler.
But unfortunately the sourced functions run in a subshell so
variables are lost after return/exit.

Finally I did it with some signal/trap/fifo mechanism to command_not_found_handle's parent shell to achieve my goal, but its everything but elegant.

Now I am wondering if `function_not_found_handle` loadable builtin could be implemented.
The builtin should be called if `command_not_found_handle ()` fails.

For the time being I found a [great article by Ed Schaefer](http://www.drdobbs.com/shell-corner-bash-dynamically-loadable-b/199102950) about this subject, but it seems to be an entrance point.

Is anyone experienced with dynamically loadable builtin bash commands?
Who could point me to useful information?

I hope to come up with some results soon to concretize my question.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the shell to know if the command you're looking for should be a function or an external command. It would have to know beforehand to decide which `x_not_found()` to call.

Comment: The priority of `x_not_found ()` functions could also follow the _shell command search sequence_ as described [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html), meaning:
`! function_not_found_handle $@ || command_not_found_handle $@`
On the other hand, found commands started by `command_not_found_handle` are started as separate process anyway, so in fact its current behavior is questionable to me.